# Not able to show the places on map, after getting the latitude and longitude from a different class

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-places

I have found the list of places in my app and I have passed the latitude and longitude to another class to show that location on map, but it is showing "Forced close application" after clicked on the listed places.

The code is :
Listing the places with onClick

```
 ListView lv = getListView();
            // listening to single list item click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem

            String lat = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lat)).getText().toString();
            String lng = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lng)).getText().toString();
            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewOnMap.class);

            in.putExtra(KEY_LAT, lat);
            in.putExtra(KEY_LONG, lng);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

Then I have created another class to show the location on map:

```
public class ViewOnMap extends MapActivity {

static final String KEY_LAT = "lat";
static final String KEY_LONG = "lng";

MapView mview;
MapController mcontrol;
LocationManager locmanager;
Location location;
GeoPoint geopoint;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

     Intent in = getIntent();

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mview.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    MapOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MapOverlay(drawable, this);


      String lat = in.getStringExtra(KEY_LAT);
      String lng = in.getStringExtra(KEY_LONG);

      int latitude = Integer.parseInt(lat);
      int longitude = Integer.parseInt(lng);

      mview =(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapv);
      mview.displayZoomControls(true);
      mview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      mcontrol =mview.getController();
      mcontrol.setZoom(9);
      GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
      OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");

      itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
      mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

Please tell me whats the mistake. These are the errors in the LogCat:

> 04-17 18:07:54.509: E/AndroidRuntime(13783): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-17 18:07:54.509: E/AndroidRuntime(13783): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.run.trial/com.run.trial.ViewOnMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-17 18:07:54.509: E/AndroidRuntime(13783):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
>   04-17 18:07:54.509: E/AndroidRuntime(13783):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
>   04-17 18:07:54.509: E/AndroidRuntime(13783):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
>   04-17 18:07:54.509: E/AndroidRuntime(13783):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
>   04-17 18:07:54.509: E/AndroidRuntime(13783):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-17 18:07:54.509: E/AndroidRuntime(13783):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   04-17 18:07:54.509: E/AndroidRuntime(13783):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)

Comment: Which error are you getting??

Comment: after getting the list of places ..when i am clicking on a place the application is getting "FoRCED CLOSED"

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION:main java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.run.trial/com.run.trial.ViewOnMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784) android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
:at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)

Comment: @santosh407 : check `in` for null  `if(in !=null)`

Comment: @KrishnaSuthar i have tried if(in!=Null) in the class from where i m atarting the activity and then within the parenthesis {StartActivity(in)};

Comment: @KrishnaSuthar the error in logcat is 04-17 18:19:59.429: E/AndroidRuntime(14551): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.run.trial/com.run.trial.ViewOnMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: you have getIntent in ViewOnMap Activity so check in ViewOnMap `in` is null or not and remove from starting activity

Comment: 04-17 18:36:55.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15432): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.run.trial/com.run.trial.ViewOnMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 18:36:55.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15432):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
04-17 18:36:55.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15432):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
04-17 18:36:55.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15432):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)

Comment: @imrankhan i have kept a toast inside the if condition and i got the above log errors

Comment: @imrankhan and also i have tried keeping the whole program code within that if ..still forced cloas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting the values through intents i have used this way to perform it...`

> `The class showing list` of places

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
          //  String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String lat = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lat)).getText().toString();
           // String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();
            String lng = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lng)).getText().toString();
            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewOnMap.class);
          //  in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
           // in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
          //  in.putExtra(KEY_LAT, lat);
           // in.putExtra(KEY_LONG, lng);

            latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
            longitude = Double.parseDouble(lng);
            ViewOnMap.putLatLong(latitude,longitude);
            startActivity(in);
```

> next in the class Showing map create one new method to get the values

```
    public class ViewOnMap extends MapActivity {
private static double lat;
private static double lng;
private int latitude;
private int longitude;
MapView mview;
MapController mcontrol;
LocationManager locmanager;
Location location;
GeoPoint geopoint;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
    mview =(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapv);
    //Intent in = getIntent();
    //  String lat = in.getStringExtra(KEY_LAT);
     // String lng = in.getStringExtra(KEY_LONG);

       latitude = (int) (lat*1e6);
       longitude = (int) (lng*1e6);

      //if(in!=null)
     mview =(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapv);
      mview.displayZoomControls(true);
      mview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      mcontrol =mview.getController();
      int maxZoom = mview.getMaxZoomLevel();
      int initZoom = (int)(0.80*(double)maxZoom);
      GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
      mcontrol.animateTo(point); 
      mcontrol.setZoom(initZoom);


    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mview.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    MapOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MapOverlay(drawable, this);


     OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "some school", "some City!");

    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
}
public static void putLatLong(double latitude, double longitude){
    lat = latitude;
    lng = longitude;
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you are trying to acces the "mview" before you set it.

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mview.getOverlays();
```

Place this line of code just after the setcontentview

```
mview =(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapv);
```

Comment: YOur code should be like this now   setContentView(R.layout.mapview);mview =(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapv);              Intent in = getIntent();      List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mview.getOverlays();

Comment: ya its the same way....but i found the other way of doing it and i got the results ..thanks for ur help SANEESH...